# How to make custom attribute be part of sign up page and also make it required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am trying to add custom attributes to the sign up page and make one of them 'required', but I am not able to do that from the console. Appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use pre-sign up lambda hook in cognito for this use case. Here is the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html)